# How do I properly work with Strings in C?

Tags: c, string, strcat

The likes of Java, Python, and others have ruined me. I'm trying to automate an FTP client by responding to server codes:

For example:

```
// I know this is ugly, please bear with me

char username[25];
strcat(username, USER); //"USER "
strcat(username, usr); // "foo"
strcat(username, "\n"); // = "USER foo\n"

char password[25];
strcat(password, PASS); //"PASS "
strcat(password, pswd); //"bar"
strcat(password, "\n"); // = "PASS bar\n"


//read/write loop

while (1) { 

    char* responsePtr;
    serverCode = readSocket(sockfd, mybuffer);

    if (serverCode == 221) 
                    break;

    if (serverCode == 220)
        responsePtr = &username;

    if (serverCode == 331)
        responsePtr = &password;

    writeSocket(sockfd, responsePtr);

}
```

When I try this, it works for USER, but I get some mangled text for PASS:

```
C->S: USER anonymous
S->C: 331 Please specify the password.
C->S: (??_?PASS random
```

Can anyone wiser and more experienced than myself give me some C string pointers? Clearly this isn't working out for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to initialize your strings before you concatenate to them. Arrays are not initialized by default.

```
char username[25] = "";
char password[25] = "";
```

For what it's worth, you can use `sprintf` to create the strings more easily:

```
sprintf(username, "USER %s\n", usr);
sprintf(password, "PASS %s\n", pswd);
```

Hopefully you also realize that using fixed size buffers is a recipe for buffer overflow bugs. For security you should make sure to guard against them. It's annoying, but that's C for you:

```
if (snprintf(username, 25, "USER %s\n", usr)  >= 25 ||
    snprintf(password, 25, "PASS %s\n", pswd) >= 25)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "buffer overflow\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: C->S: USER anonymous
S->C: 331 Please specify the password.
C->S: PASS random
S->C: 230 Login successful.

:)

Comment: I just reloaded and saw your sprintf addition. Thanks for the tip, I've been looking for a better way to concat my strings.

Comment: I usually `strcpy` first, then `strcat` the rest. I guess its preference.

Comment: Recommendation: replace the magic number 25 with sizeof username

Comment: @Marlon It isn't just precedence; strcpy and strcat produce buffer overflow security holes waiting to happen. Use snprintf or, better, a dynamic string library (or a modern computer language).

Answer (score 1):

A few rules that help.

- Remember to initialize and null terminate your strings.
- Use the library functions.
- Check the string lengths and/or use n (size limited) functions when working with external data.
- Don't forget the terminator when sizing buffers.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't strcat an uninitialized array.
Try:

```
char *password[25] = "";
password = strcat(PASS);
```

for the fist one.

Also, instead of `strcat()` you should use `strncat()` to avoid overflows.

---

I think it's easier to do:

```
int len = snprintf(password, 25, "%s %s\n", PASS, pswd);
if (len > 25) {
    // oops! password is too long dude :-(
}
```

[See here for some examples](http://libslack.org/manpages/snprintf.3.html).

Comment: Does a mod have to lock a post?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding "\n\0" instead of just "\n" to the username and password arrays.

Comment: I already tried that -- wouldn't really matter, though, considering the junk is coming before the string, not after it. And, besides, \n is a delimiter for FTP so \0 doesn't really matter.

Comment: okey doke. I thought the junk might be there because of an issue server-side.

Comment: couldn't be. I simply parse the server code (331 in this case) and set my pointer to a new string. The string doesn't have much to do with what the server's doing. But thanks anyway :)